# Find the element where the minimum value is stored

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a pretty trivial question but I can't find anything on the internet covering it. 
I need to find the index in a 1D array where the minimum value is stored. 
Everything I found so far only tells you the value of the minimum value.
Code I made an attempt with is:

```
int min_element_loc (double a[]){
double first, last;
first = a[0];
last = a[255];
for(int i = 0;i<256;i++)
{
    if (first==last) return i;
    double smallest = first;
      while (++first!=last)
          smallest=first;
      return i;
}
return 0;
}
```

(The array has 256 elements in it : I know its messy but it will never change, and the program is not in final version)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the index of the minimum value?

Comment: There's a bit too much wrong with your code to show you how in a code snippet, but the way you do it is to store `i` also, in the same way that you're storing  `smallest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use std::min_element found in the algorithm header.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<double> vals = { 1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 4.2 };

    auto iter = std::min_element(vals.begin(), vals.end());
    auto idx = iter - vals.begin();

    std::cout << idx << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works however, I would need to add my array to a vector. Which I have no idea how to do. edit, I looked it up, thanks :)

Comment: Future Reference:  `std::vector<double> vals;
    double a[256];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++)
    {
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    vals.insert(vals.begin(), a, a+256);
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i ++ )
    {
        cout << vals[i]<<endl;
    }`

Comment: @Sizza *"I would need to add my array to a vector."* No, you don't. Just do this: `std::min_element(a, a+256);`. However, I would also strongly suggest that you use `std::vector` in your *entire* program instead of C style arrays; you can easily make stack corruptions with `double a[256]` and friends.

Comment: @Sizza: if all you need is submitting your homework and moving on, go ahead and use standard library algorithms. If you want to make progress, stop righth here. Forget the standard algorithms. Implement your own. This is an absolute imperative if you ever want to actually do something with code. Once you know how to implement your own, or at the very least end up in the right ballpark, go ahead and use the standard library.